# filter some rows of a data frame depending values of others rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I would like to filter some rows of a dataframe based on the values of other rows and I don't know how to proceed. Below is an example of what I want to do.

```
data=data.frame(ID=c("ID1",NA, NA, "ID2", NA, "ID3", NA, NA), 
                l2=c(NA,9,4,NA,5,NA,6,8), 
                var3=c("aa", NA, NA, "bc",NA, "cc", NA, NA), 
                var4=c(NA,"yes","no",NA,"yes",NA,"yes","no"))


> data
    ID l2 var3 var4
1  ID1 NA   aa <NA>
2 <NA>  9 <NA>  yes
3 <NA>  4 <NA>  no
4  ID2 NA   bc <NA>
5 <NA>  5 <NA>  yes
6  ID3 NA   cc <NA>
7 <NA>  6 <NA>  yes
8 <NA>  8 <NA>  no
```

On this dataframe I would like to select the rows using the ID variable if the rows following this ID (until the next one) have at least one value < 7 for the l2 variable AND a "yes" for the var4 variable.
Following this rule I would expect the following output.
This is just an example, I have much more rows and much more other variables.
If someone have a solution with dplyr it would be perfect.

```
> outpout=data.frame(ID=c("ID2","ID3"), l2=c(NA,NA), var3=c( "bc","cc"), var4=c(NA,NA))

> outpout
   ID l2 var3 var4
1 ID2 NA   bc   NA
2 ID3 NA   cc   NA
```

Comment: One question about "have at least one value < 7 for the l2 variable AND a "yes" for the var4 variable". Does this mean the same row has to have l2<7 and var4 = yes or could it also be ok if e.g. row two has l2 <7 but var4 = no, but then row 3 has var4= yes (but not ls <7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

### a) if it would be ok if the conditions for `l2` and `var4` could be satisfied in different rows:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  fill(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter((any(l2 < 7) & any(var4 == "yes")) & row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID       l2 var3  var4 
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 ID1      NA aa    NA   
2 ID2      NA bc    NA   
3 ID3      NA cc    NA
```

### b) if the conditions for `l2` and `var4` have to be satisfied in the same row (could probably be simplified a bit, but I be a bit more verbose here for illustrative purposes):

```
data %>%
  fill(ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter((l2 < 7 & var4 == "yes") | row_number() == 1) %>%
  filter(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ID       l2 var3  var4 
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 ID2      NA bc    NA   
2 ID3      NA cc    NA
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thank you ! This is working but I don't understand the difference between the two conditions. I feel this is the B that I need when reading the condition, but the A is also working whereas it shouldn't because for ID1 the l2 and the var4 are satisfied in different row (row 2 for l2 and row 3 for var4) and is not selected in output.

Comment: Sorry, the was indeed a bug in solution a). This is now fixed and should better illustrate the differences. With solution a) we now would keep ID 1, because the condition for l2 is met in any row and the condition in var4 is also met in any row (could be the same row as l2, but also a different row). Solution b) however, requires that the condition for l2 and var 4 are met in the same row, which is not the case for ID1.

Comment: If the answer solves your question/problem, please consider accepting the answer so that others can benefit from it.